# Clicking JavaScript objects & classes in a loop simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing this short JavaScript script. 
Requirement:

(A) Object `$(".img-aspect a")` should be clicked by clicking on a class `'.zoom-overlay'`. 
NOTE: `$(".img-aspect a")` can't be clicked directly due to CSS styling. We should first click on `'.zoom-overlay'`.

(B) Object and class are a part of LIST item, and there's more than one LIST item. How to click on a particular object and class that are attached to the same LIST? This is a requirement for the slideshow to work properly.

(C) The following script I have written clicked through all the objects and classes in LIST items and opens the last image in a slideshow. For example, if I want to click on the first LIST item or any other items, then how can I modify the script? Any guidance will be of immense help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', '.zoom-overlay', function (event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        $(".img-aspect a").click();
    });

</script>      

  <ul>
        <li class="gallery-item" >
            <div class="center-crop">
                <div class="img-aspect">
                    <a href="https://image.net">
                        <img class="thumbnail-image"
                             title="..."
                             alt="..."
                             src="https://image.net">
                        <div class="active-indicator"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="zoom-overlay">
                    <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it helps you try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.zoom-overlay', function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".img-aspect").child("a").click();
});
```

Comment: I changed .child("a") to .children("a"), and it worked!

Comment: i forgot little bit about jquery but i am glad to help you